# GoogleMap null when trying to access it from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments in my application. Ons is a map fragment and the other is a list fragment. Both of these are added to a single activity. The idea is that when a user is selected from the list, the app switches to the map fragment and displays the user. The problem is that I am getting a nullPointer exception on the GoogleMap object.

I know that the map works, because on a button press in the map fragment, I can see my current location, and I do not get 'n NullPointer.

This is the onClickListener in my ListFragment:

```
listEmployees.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ChildUser childUser = children.get(position);
            Tracker.showMapFragment(childUser);
        }
    });
```

This is the function that is called from my ListFragment in my parent Activity:

```
public static void showMapFragment(ChildUser childUser) {

    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    MapFragment.showSelectedUser(childUser);
    trackingEmployee = true;
}
```

This is the applicable code in my MapFragment:

Initialisation:

```
mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("MAP", "on activity created");
        googleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        }
    };

    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map, mMapFragment).commit();
```

The showSelectedUser function:

```
public static void showSelectedUser(ChildUser childUser) {

    try {
        googleMap.clear();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(childUser.getChildLatitude(), childUser.getChildLongetude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15);

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.position(point);

        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException at `googleMap.clear();`. Please advise me as to what I can possibly be doing wrong as it works fine when I show my current location from within the MapFragment. Please let me know if you need additional information. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

When the MapFragment is visible and I press a button, I can view the users current location in the MapFragment with the following code:

```
public static void showUserLocation() {

    googleMap.clear();
    if (Tracker.clockedInShift) {
        CacheUploads cacheUpload = new CacheUploads(context);
        LatLng point = cacheUpload.getMostRecentLocation();
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.position(point);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
}
```

The map is linked up correctly because this code gets executed successfully. Why is the googleMap object null when accessed from the ListFragment? Please let me know if you require more information! Thanks

Comment: Please don't downvote without a reason, so I can remedy the problem

Comment: you are passing custom object, means are you sure you are passing correct values showMapFragment.

Comment: Yes, I have checked, the correct long + lat values go through to the MapFragment every time, and I still get the error @user3676184

Comment: @user3676184 The application crashes before it gets to using the custom object that I pass through. As stated in the question, I get a NullPointer when I call googleMap.clear()

Comment: please comment googleMap.clear() and check what's output?

Comment: @user3676184 I get a NullPointer at googleMap.addmarker(marker). The googleMap object seems to be Null, but I do not understand why, so havent been able to fix it :/

Comment: on which device you are running that apk?

Comment: i think your mMapFragment is not linked with the XML containing the map. so try to change initialization like MapFragment fm = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); and then do googleMap = fm.getMap();

Comment: @Gautam Hey, have a look at the update that I made to my question. I can display the current users location when I push a button in the MapFragment. Things go wrong when I try to do the same from the ListFragment

Comment: @user3676184 A couple, GS2 + GS3 + GS3 LTE + Google nexus 5. Testers have additional devices, unaware of all of them. The problem is not device related

Comment: Check putting debug point near this statement

    googleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

also try putting this statements to other methods

Comment: @TechnodHr I have debugged the application as well, and the above is what I have found. The googleMap works fine, but when I select a user from the list and the app switches back to the MapFragment, the googleMap object is null

Comment: @TechnodHr I have added the statements to onMapLoaded callback as well, but the result is the same

Comment: When you come back to the mapFragment from ListFragment googleMap object is null?? first time when mapFragment gets executed before going to List Fragment, Map Fragment works well?? Am I right?

Comment: @Keshav1234 Yes you are correct

Comment: before going to ListFragment are you adding MapFragment to backstack?

Comment: @Keshav1234 FML, I fixed it just now. Your comment reminded me of something I did. I will post the answer as soon as I can. :)

Comment: Cool. Even I had an idea. Any how good you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer to this question was fairly obvious. Using an inner class solved the problem. The following code solved everything:

```
private static GoogleMap googleMap;

public static class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    public MyMapFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public static MyMapFragment newInstance() {
        MyMapFragment frag = new MyMapFragment();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        googleMap = getMap();
        return v;
    }
}
```

Then just use googleMap to do whatever you want. The above code should be in your Activity/Fragment.